# Disperse distinct balls into identical bins with extra conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801451/distributing-balls-into-bins-with-some-conditions/4801463?noredirect=1#comment10211517_4801463) today. I have problem in the second part:

> In how many ways can 4 red balls and 7 blue balls be arranged in 3 boxes where each box must contain at least 1 red ball and each box can contain less than or equal or 4 balls, under the following cases?
>
> (1) Each ball is distinct and Each box is distinct
>
> (2) Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical

I have calculated the first part using generating functions and another user gave me another method. However, we could not agree with the part $2$.

We know that the distribution of ball would be $(r^2b)(rb^3)(rb^3)$ or $(r^2b^2)(rb^2)(rb^3)$

- for $(r^2b)(rb^3)(rb^3)$:Let $(r^2b)=a,(rb^3)=b$ , we can arrange them in a line $3!/2!=3$ ways. Thus, $$3\times\binom42\binom71\binom21\binom63$$ if the boxes were distinct

If we want to make the boxes identical, then divide by $3!$, so $$\frac{1}{2}\times\binom42\binom71\binom21\binom63=840$$

- for $(r^2b^2)(rb^2)(rb^3)$ . Let $(r^2b^2)=a,(rb^2)=b,(rb^3)=c$ . We can arrange them in line by $3!$ ways. So, the answer is $$6\times\binom42\binom72\binom21\binom52$$ if the boxes were distinct.

If we want to convert them into identical, then divide by $3!$, so the answer is  $$\binom42\binom72\binom21\binom52=2520$$

So, $$840+2520=3360$$

@trueblueanil claims that the answer is $4200$. Who is right ?

Comment: I don't understand the nomenclature. If each box is "identical", what is it identical with? If all boxes are identical, then ther
e is only one box. The usual nomenclature would be to talk about labelled boxes (such the the could be ordered left to right with different enumeration of the results) or unlabelled boxes (such that permutation of boxes with the same content would not add to the final count).